# Why is my HashMap not getting populated

Tags: java, hashmap

My code for finding factorial for integers upto 100.I am using BigInteger, but my problem is that my HashMap is not getting populated.

```
public class FCTRL2 {   
static Map<Integer,BigInteger> list = new HashMap<Integer,BigInteger>();

  public static void main(String[] args){
        InputStreamReader read = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(read);
        int numberOfInput=0;
        String input=null;
        try {
            numberOfInput = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        while(numberOfInput > 0){
            try {
                input = in.readLine();
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            BigInteger inputBig = new BigInteger(input);
            **System.out.println(factorial(inputBig));** prints correct factorial
        **System.out.println(list.get(factorial(inputBig).intValue()));** prints null
            numberOfInput--;
        }
  }

  public static BigInteger factorial(BigInteger input){
    if(list.containsKey(input.intValue()))
        return list.get(input.intValue());

    if(input.equals(new BigInteger("1")))
        return new BigInteger("1");
    BigInteger output;
    output = input.multiply(factorial(input.subtract(new BigInteger("1"))));
    list.put(input.intValue(), output);
    return output;
  }

}
```

Comment: Did you try debugging? Does the code ever reach `list.put()`? Why is a `Map` variable called `list`?

Comment: I don't get what is not working.

Comment: @Warthel4578 just added two Sysout statements in code,with their output, please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace

```
System.out.println(list.get(factorial(inputBig).intValue()));
```

with

```
System.out.println(list.get(inputBig.intValue()));
```

because You are inserting value to map here: `list.put(input.intValue(), output);`

Comment: even if I keep it `System.out.println(list.get(factorial(inputBig).intValue()));`, it should not differ in result, because inside my function, it will check if the map already contains the key or not, and if it does, it will return the BigInt.

Comment: It will be different in result because your function return `return map.get(input.intValue());` if map contains a key insted just `return input.intValue()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public static BigInteger factorial(BigInteger input) {
    if (list.containsKey(input.intValue()))
        return list.get(input.intValue());

    if (input.equals(BigInteger.ONE)) {
        list.put(input.intValue(), BigInteger.ONE);
        return BigInteger.ONE;  
    }
    BigInteger output = input.multiply(factorial(input.subtract(BigInteger.ONE)));
    list.put(input.intValue(), output);
    return output;
}
```

And add a print after your `numberOfInput` while loop...

```
for (int key : list.keySet()) {
    System.out.println(list.get(key));
}
```

Seems to correctly output

```
1
10
3628800
1
2
6
24
120
720
5040
40320
362880
3628800
```

Comment: Hi, I made changed in the factorial, and I guess your for loop is only for debugging purposes, hence i did not do that. Now here's my input, 

5 (ie the number of testcases) -> 2(input) -> 2(output) 2(output) -> 3(input) -> 6(output) -> null

I am printing twice in my code, check edits (for debuggin purpose). Can you check if you are getting the same results.?

Answer (score 0):

I did a test,first simplify read data,focus on logic:

I use BigInteger.valueOf() .

```
public class FCTRL2 {   

  public static void main(String[] args){

        InputStreamReader read = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(read);
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(in);
        //simplify read data first ,here focus on calculation logic
        while(scanner.hasNext()) {
             long val = scanner.nextLong();
             BigInteger inputBig = BigInteger.valueOf(val);
             System.out.println(factorial(inputBig));
        }
        scanner.close();
  }

  public static BigInteger factorial(BigInteger input){
    if(map.containsKey(input.intValue())) {
        System.out.println("from map");
         return map.get(input.intValue());
    }
    if(input.equals(new BigInteger("1")))
        return new BigInteger("1");
    BigInteger output;
    output = input.multiply(factorial(input.subtract(new BigInteger("1"))));
    map.put(input.intValue(), output);
    System.out.println("from new calculating");
    return output;
  }
  private static Map<Integer,BigInteger> map = new HashMap<Integer,BigInteger>();
}
```

**see output and it seems the map cached some data**.

Is this the logic what you want ?